# May I optimize shader programs by merge some of them?

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader, fragment-shader, vertex-shader

EX, I have two shader program.

**The first is 1st vertex shader + 1st frag shader.**

**The second is 2nd vertex shader + 2nd frag shader.**

The 1st and 2nd vertex shader are indentical (do nothing).

**Now I found 1st and 2nd frag shader can be merged.**

**It becomes 1st vertex shader + merged(1st + 2nd) frag shader.**

So **I have a unique shader program now**.

My question is: **is ther any benefit (either speed or operation saving) of the merged version over original one??**

Intuitively, it seems that I can save some operations and data transder (?? not sure); ex:
call shader one time in my main control program.

How could you do when think about speedup or save operations to Shader programmming?

Comment: You use shaders to convert model's vertices and their attributes into pixels on the screen (framebuffer in general). Now if you have many shaders and you call them all every frame, you basically draw something with first shader, then overdraw it with another shader and so on. You'd want is to reduce the number of overdraws (aka draw calls). So it's beneficial for you to combine shaders if it reduces number of draws. It's also beneficial to combine geometry of identical objects with same materials into a single vertex array